# Sketchy Advice in the FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, on-topic-definition

In [the FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) under the heading [**What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), the following advice is given:

> If your question would be of interest to …
>
> - **Professional and enthusiast programmers**, ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Of course, there are some questions that should be asked on Stack Overflow because they are of interest to professional and enthusiast programmers, but that's not the main reason a question should be asked on Stack Overflow instead of Programmers.SE. Indeed, the entire premise for Programmers.SE is... *to ask questions that would be of interest to professional and enthusiast programmers*.

This part of the FAQ is misleading at best, incorrect at worst, and really ought to be removed.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood should add a diamond next to your name so that you can be empowered to go clean it up. ;)

Comment: @jmort Diamonds can't change that part. See Jeff's answer.

Comment: @Anna - I saw that after I made my comment.  But still, I think Mark should be made a moderator to help where help is needed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is built algorithmically based on the unlocked migration paths.

The string you're referring to is the "audience" string for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators don't have access to editing that part of the FAQ, but the part that we do have access to has the following clarification:

> If your question is about ...
>
> **Specific programming problem, software
>   algorithms, coding**, ask on Stack
>   Overflow.
>   **System administration**, ask
>   on Server Fault.
>    **General computer
>   software or hardware troubleshooting**,
>   ask on Super User.